# Typescript - Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm following a tutorial in React that creates a useForm hook to hook form input to state

The hook looks like

```
const useForm = (initial = {}) => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(initial)

    const handleChange = (e:any) => {
        let {value,name,type} = e.target
        if(type === 'number'){
             value = parseInt(value)
        }
        if(type === 'file'){
            value[0] = e.target.files
        }
        setInputs({
            ...inputs,
            [name]: value
        })
    }
    
    return{
        inputs,
        handleChange,
        resetForm,
        clearForm
    }
}

export default useForm
```

And it's used in the page like

```
import useForm from "../lib/useForm";

const CreateProduct = () => {

    const {inputs, handleChange, clearForm, resetForm} = useForm({
        name: 'name test',
        price: 1234,
        description: 'description test'
    })

    return (
        <form>
            <label htmlFor="name">
                Name: 
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    id="name" 
                    name="name" 
                    placeholder="name" 
                    value={inputs.name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            <label htmlFor="name">
                Name: 
                <input 
                    type="number" 
                    id="price" 
                    name="price" 
                    placeholder="price" 
                    value={inputs.price}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
        </form>
    );

};

export default CreateProduct;
```

The tutorial is is js but I want it in typescript.

In the typescript here `value={inputs.name}` I get the following error `Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.`

How can I stop this error

I have tried to add an interface for inputs but this just errors, am I hiding the interface wrong here

```
import { string } from "prop-types";
import useForm from "../lib/useForm";

interface inputProps{
    name: string,   
    price: number,
    decription: string 
}

const CreateProduct = () => {

    const {(inputs):inputProps, handleChange, clearForm, resetForm} = useForm({
        name: 'name test',
        price: 1234,
        description: 'description test'
    })

    return (
        <form>
            <label htmlFor="name">
                Name: 
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    id="name" 
                    name="name" 
                    placeholder="name" 
                    value={inputs.name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            <label htmlFor="name">
                Name: 
                <input 
                    type="number" 
                    id="price" 
                    name="price" 
                    placeholder="price" 
                    value={inputs.price}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            <button type="button" onClick={clearForm}>Clear Form</button>
            <button type="button" onClick={resetForm}>Reset Form</button>
        </form>
    );

};

export default CreateProduct;
```

Comment: You'd have to update useForm to have a generic type parameter, as e.g. useState does, so that you can describe the relationship between the inputs and outputs. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html.

Comment: I think I see what you mean but the `useState` here doesn't have a generic type does it ?

Comment: You're not using the generic parameter, but it does take one.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you haven't typed your hook properly.

I would suggest creating an input type and passing it in as a generic type when you define the hook, i'll show you an example.

```
type InputType = {
    name: string,   
    price: number,
    decription: string 
}
```

```
    const {inputs, handleChange, clearForm, resetForm} = useForm<InputType>({
        name: 'name test',
        price: 1234,
        description: 'description test'
    })
```

```
const useForm = <T>(initial: T) => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(initial)

    const handleChange = (e:any) => {
        let {value,name,type} = e.target
        if(type === 'number'){
             value = parseInt(value)
        }
        if(type === 'file'){
            value[0] = e.target.files
        }
        setInputs({
            ...inputs,
            [name]: value
        })
    }
    
    return{
        inputs,
        handleChange,
        resetForm,
        clearForm
    }
}

export default useForm
```

I've done this as a generic type so you will be able to change the props that go into that hook if you end up using it somewhere else in the future.

Comment: On `<T>` I get the error `JSX element 'T' has no corresponding closing tag.ts Cannot find name 'T'.`

Comment: try adding a trailing comma after it like this `<T,>`

Comment: yeah thats worked but why, Ive never seem that before

Comment: Its because typescript uses the same syntax as JSX and so your compiler sometimes isn't able to tell what is and isn't JSX, adding the comma allows it to infer that if is not JSX and so treats it properly as typescript. I'll admit its been a while since i've encountered this issue.